# using collection in generic function

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I was trying to use a generic function for 2 kinds of Collections, in which I call the method Add.

So below my Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace CollectionsApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void AddElement<T>(ref T container, string key, string value)
        {
            container.Add(key, value);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SortedList s1 = new SortedList();
            Hashtable  h1 = new Hashtable();

            AddElement<SortedList>(ref s1, "001", "Zara Ali");
            AddElement<Hashtable>(ref h1, "001", "Zara Ali");
        }
    }
}
```

and below the error :

> error CS1061: 'T' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no
>   extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'T'

So Could this be performed and how to fix it if possible ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: On an unrelated note, the use of `ref` is unnecessary as you are not reassigning the variable.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 : sorry I came from C++  and it my first prog using C# ;) Thx

Comment: But really, what's the point? Where it could be helpful (instead of using already defined `Add()` method)?

Comment: @SeM it doesn't need to have a helpful in my case, I was just trying to manipulate generics & collections. defined Add works :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that T can be anything (e.g. an int) and isn't guaranteed to have an Add method.

You need to constrain T to something that has an Add method.

```
static void AddElement<T>(ref T container, string key, string value)
    where T : IDictionary 
{
    container.Add(key, value);
}
```

Comment: `IEnumerable` doesn't contain `Add` either. You need non-generic `IDictionary` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Why not make it easier, like so?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace CollectionsApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void AddElement(IDictionary container, string key, string value)
        {
            container.Add(key, value);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SortedList s1 = new SortedList();
            Hashtable  h1 = new Hashtable();

            AddElement(s1, "001", "Zara Ali");
            AddElement(h1, "001", "Zara Ali");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah make sens :) I tried to manipulate some generic with collections and didn't know about *IDictionnary*.

Answer (score 2):

Or create an extension method:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static void AddElement(this IDictionary container, string key, string value)
    {
        container.Add(key, value);
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
SortedList s1 = new SortedList();
Hashtable h1 = new Hashtable();

s1.AddElement("001", "Zara Ali");
h1.AddElement("001", "Zara Ali");
```

Comment: nice, love this concept of extension method